# Drop a foreign key from a table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

I have created a foreign key without giving it a name for a column in a table. Now i want to remove that column. First i've tried removing the foreign key constraint but there was an error 
I've used the following sql command

```
ALTER TABLE passenger 
DROP FOREIGN KEY bookedBy
```

The error message

> #1091 - Can't DROP 'bookedBy'; check that column/key exists

i've ensured that the column exist.
I have not named the foreign key constraint. Is it possible to remove the foreign key constraint without naming it. Is there any default naming given to the foreign keys.

Comment: Perhaps alter table drop column cascade?

Comment: Do you use PhpMyAdmin? There you can use UI to access Keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the statement **`SHOW CREATE TABLE passenger`**.

The output from that will show the foreign key constraints, as well as the columns in the table. You should be able to figure out the name of the foreign key constraint you want to drop from that.

Or, you can muck with your queries of the tables in `information_schema` database. It's going to show up in there as well.

---

**Followup**

One possible query of `information_schema` to find the names of the foreign key constraints for a given table:

```
 SELECT kcu.constraint_schema
      , kcu.constraint_name
  --  , kcu.*
   FROM information_schema.key_column_usage kcu
  WHERE kcu.referenced_table_name IS NOT NULL 
    AND kcu.constraint_schema = 'mydatabase'
    AND kcu.table_name        = 'mytablename'
```

Comment: yeah querying the information_schema database worked.

Answer (score 11):

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
  O_Id int NOT NULL,
  OrderNo int NOT NULL,
  P_Id int,
  PRIMARY KEY (O_Id),
  FOREIGN KEY (P_Id) REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)
)
```

also you can add foreign key like this

```
ALTER TABLE Orders
ADD FOREIGN KEY (P_Id)
REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)
```

and delete

```
ALTER TABLE Orders
DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_PerOrders
```

How to find foreign key in my table

```
   SELECT
         TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,CONSTRAINT_NAME,
REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
    WHERE
      REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = '<table>';
```

Comment: Thanks - the DROP FOREIGN KEY is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Find out the name of the foreign key:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table_name;
```

then you can drop it using the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table_name DROP FOREIGN KEY foreign_key_name;
```

---

follow this(**Old Answer**)

1. Log to phpMyAdmin
2. Check which field you need to `DROP`(Ex I will use Product )

[image]

3. then Select

[image]

4. UnCheck this checkbox and click `YES`

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The quickest and dirtiest way is to turn off foreign key checks, drop the table and then turn the checks back on

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

drop table mytable

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Comment: The question is about removing foreign key, not the entire table.

Comment: A "nice" way to... delete all the data. Please add a note about this in the answer itself, since deleting everything was not requested by the question.